# Add placeholder in filter of ng-table

Tags: css, placeholder, ngtable

Hi can someone help me with this?

How can I have a placeholder inside the textbox in td?

here is the code

```
<td data-title="'Effectivity Date'" filter="{ 'date_from':'text','date_to':'text' }">{{item.date_start | dateToISO | date:'MMM-dd-yyyy'}}</td>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can correct `ng-table.js`

Unminify `ng-table.js` and after that in line 250 we can find

```
<input type="text" ng-model="params.filter [name]" ng-if="filter==\'text\'" ,class="input-filter form-control"/>
```

add `placeholder` there ie :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="params.filter [name]" ng-if="filter==\'text\'" placeholder="input {{name}}",class="input-filter form-control"/>
```

***Operative demo :***

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/q0CMCb7evmZh1sflVV5f?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Very bad answer. You should NEVER edit vendor-libs! If you want to update them at one point, you'll lose all your changes.

Instead just overwrite the template in your angular-app's run-block via $templateCache:

```
$templateCache.put('ng-table/filters/text.html',
    '<input type="text" ng-model="params.filter [name]" ng-if="filter==\'text\'" placeholder="input {{name}}" class="input-filter form-control"/>');
```